# Is there a way to display raw html code in a template literal?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I know it may seem counter intuitive but I'm looking for a way to display raw html code within a Typescript template (template literal), as in to not allow the template to interpret it as html or display it as an element.

It can be achieved by replacing any `<` or `>` brackets with html entities but that is not very efficient. `String.raw()` doesn't seem to work either.

So trying to achieve something like

```
const code = '<div>hello</div>';
template: `<div>This is the ${code}</div>`;
```

which would output

```
This is the <div>hello</div>
```

within a `div`.

Comment: Code is not allowed in a template literal.

Comment: There are numerous code embed tools and scripts you can use to simplify this as well as have syntax highlighting for your displayed code

Comment: Why would you call replacing html entities "inefficient"?

Comment: @Gershom Just because if you're trying to display a more elaborate piece of html it gets quite messy.

Comment: @charlietfl Can you point me in the right direction of these tools and scripts?

Comment: Let google be your friend. Asking for resource recommendations is off topic on SO

Comment: @Crowbar I think it will only be messy if you're coding by hand. Why not use some server-side technology (or even clientside javascript) to do the conversion automatically?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll have a look.